# how to run (launch) recent task from recent task list from a android service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recents

I am trying to launch last recent task from task list in android .
 Using ActivityManager  to get list of tasks. This will get me task id,baseintent etc
    ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager)ChatHeadService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        List recentTasks = m.getRecentTasks(2, 
                                ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);

this is the code i am using to get last .

but when i run this its not switching .

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        am.moveTaskToFront(apps.id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
                    } else { // API 10 and below (Gingerbread on down)
                        Intent restartTaskIntent = new Intent(apps.baseIntent);
                        if (restartTaskIntent != null) {
                            restartTaskIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
                            try {
                                startActivity(restartTaskIntent);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Log.w("MyApp", "Unable to launch recent task", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

This is also not working for me.

I am looking for apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mohammad.adib.switchr)

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: Do you have permission `android.permission.REORDER_TASKS`? You need this to be able to call `ActivityManager.moveTaskToFront()`

Comment: Testing on 4.4.2 ART (nexus 4)

Comment: I have android.permission.REORDER_TASK permission. No security exception is there.

Comment: Try commenting out the code in the `if` statement and always execute the code in the `else` statement (ie: don't use `moveTaskToFront()` but instead use `startActivity(restartTaskIntent)`) and see if that works on your device

Comment: Got answer ? i want to do same bhat maam :p